# How can I abandon manual control of all my ships?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

Sometimes I'd like to give all my ships orders and let the AI work on them without my manual intervention. 
So far however, I always had to control one ship manually. Can I give up on that and let the AI do all the work?

I'd like to use this to do the boring stuff, like flying across a larger map or collecting Rez.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way to relinquish controls on all of your ships.

1. Select a ship (any ship).
2. Go into the tactics menu and click on sell.  This forces you to relinquish control.
3. Close the tactics menu.
4. Before the sell finishes, open the tactics menu again and cancel the sell.

Now, all your ships will be in automatic mode and you can direct them via the tactics menu.

Comment: That's not what I wanted. It is a more difficult version of just sitting around and letting one ship idle, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @ver I figured out a way and updated my answer

Comment: that's a real pain in the neck to do, but better than a poke in the eye with a sharp stick.

Answer (score 0):

In the tactics screen `F2` you can tell your ships to go to specific places. such as to rez deposits. If they have a tractor beam they will automatically pick up stuff from there. But I haven't seen any sign of giving them roles, which I also hoped for. Also of note in the advanced tactics button at the top right there is the option for muling that says it will allow smaller ships to pass off their cargo to larger ships.

Comment: So far the tactics option is the only way to go, though they're working in improving that aspect of the game right now with waypoints and other stuff.

Comment: That doesn't help. I can give my ships orders, but the one I'm 'controlling' will just ignore them, anyway.